# C# + представление из SQL

Tags: c#

есть написанное представление в базе данных MSSQL , как мне его показать через DataGridView и если есть у кого пример или где можно почитать как использовать хранимки и функции написанные в базе и сделать их в базе, я так понимаю через приложение передавать параметры в базу, в базе работать с хранимками и функциями более менее могу, а вот в приложении не пробовал

Comment: SqlCommand. CommandType посмотрите примеры. А вьюха это та же таблица только для чтения

Answer (score 0):

Если попроще, то [Работа с хранимыми процедурами](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.11.php).
Но лучше изучите какую-либо ORM, к примеру Entity Framework. В сети масса информации.